# Only starred places are visible during route planning

Tags: google-maps

I'm using several types of bookmarks - `Starred places` and custom made from `New list` `holidays 2018`

[image]

But why during route planning I see `Starred places` and there is no `holidays 2018`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this is (probably) due to a bug in Google Maps.

whenever you enter directions it will automatically hide your labels (all except those with star) even if they are set as unhidden and/or public

[image]

however, there is a way how to show them during entering directions with the mouse if you deselect the last point that was selected as a destination

[image]